# Como fazer para o MySQL aceitar um numero do tipo 1.457,40?

Tags: mysql

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que precisar exportar automaticamente planilhas excel para o banco de dados. Estou usando o MySQL, porém os dados da planilha não estão todos bem formatados do jeito que o banco aceita.

Já setei como `utf8_general_ci`, todas as tabelas com `utf8` e não resolveu. O problema esta quando eu leio um numero do tipo `1.478,45` e ele não consegue armazenar em uma variável do tipo `double` ou `float`.

Como proceder?

Comment: Porque o número não segue esse formato. Ele só tem divisão do ponto decimal (não tem o separador de milhar). E normalmente o separador decimal é "`.`" e não "`,`" exceto se estiver configurado com o locale adequado

Comment: E nem deveria ser armazenado neste formato. No DB o dado deve sempre que possível ser armazenado pelo seu valor, não pela sua "estética". Armazenar número com separador de milhar no DB é _quase_ como querer "armazenar um texto em negrito". O DB não tem esses conceitos visuais.

Answer (score 3):

Na sua linguagem de programação preferida, faça algo como:

```
var numero = foo; // onde "foo" é o número quebrado;
numero = (numero + '').replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
```

Answer (score 3):

Cara como nosso amigo disse antes, no mysql ele utiliza o padrão americano de moeda que segue este padrão '15,123.50' .

Ao contrario do padrão brasileiro que é '15.123,50' que é ao contrario como vc viu.

porem no BD mysql alem de ser padrão americano ele nao conta as casas de milhares ficando assim '15123.50' .... sendo assim vc deve fazer uma forma de colocar neste padrão na linguagem utilizada por vc !!

Em PHP eu faço da seguinte forma amigo :

```
valor = valor.replace(".", "") ; //IMPORTANTE - Tirar os pontos (a cada 3 dígitos, exemplo, 1.355.000,00)
valor = valor.replace(",", ".") ; // Depois remover a virgula da casa decimal por ponto, ficando no padrão d mysql
```